# python basic regex function

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a function that implements a simple regex matching algorithm. The special characters "*" and "?" should stand for 1 and n>=0 degrees of freedom respectively. For example the strings

```
y="abc" and x="a*c",
y="abc" and x="a?c",
y="abddddzfjc" and x="a?" or x="a?c"
```

should return True, whereas the strings

```
y="abcd" and x="a*d",
y="abcdef" and x="a?d*"
```

should return False.

My method is to run in a loop and shorten the strings as each subsequent match is identified, which works fine for identical matches or single * with alphabet character matches, but I am a stumped on about how to do it for edge cases like the last example. To handle the case where "?" has n degrees of freedom, I loop forward in the right string to find the next alphabet character, then try to find that character in the left string, looking from right to left. I am sure there is a more elegant way (maybe with a generator?!).

```
def match_func(x,y):
  x, y = list(x), list(y)
  if len(x)==len(y)==1:
    if x[0] == y[0] or bool((set(x)|set(y)) & {"?","*"})
    return True
  elif len(x)>0 and len(y)==0:
    return False
  else:
    for ix, char in enumerate(x):
      if char==y[ix] or char=="*":
        return match_func(x[ix+1:],y[ix+1:])
      else:
        if char=="?"
          if ix==len(x)=1: return True
          ##check if the next letter in x has an eventual match in y
          peek = ix+1
          next_char = x[peek]

          while peek<len(x)-1:
            next_char = x[peek]
            if next_char.isalpha():
              break
            else: peek+=1

          if peek == len(x)-1:
            return True

          ys = ''.join(y)

          next_char_ix = ys[ix].rfind(next_char)
          ##search y for next possible match?

          if next_char_ix!=-1:
            return match_func(x[peek:], y[next_char_ix:])
          else:
            return False

        else:
          return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

First decide whether to make your match algorithm a *minimal* or *maximal* search.  Meaning, if your pattern is `a`, and your subject string is `aa`, does the match occur at the first or second position?  As you state the problem, either choice seems to be acceptable.

Having made that choice, it will become clear how you should traverse the string - either as far to the right as possible and then working backward until you either match or fail; or starting at the left and backtracking after each attempt.

I recommend a recursive implementation either way.  At each position, evaluate whether you have a possible match.  If so, make your recursive call advancing the appropriate amount down both the pattern and subject string.  If not, give up.  If there is no match for the first character of the pattern, advance only the subject string (according to your minimal/maximal choice) and try again.

The tricky part is, you have to consider variable-length tokens in your pattern as possible matches even if the same character also matches a literal character following that wildcard.  That puts you in the realm of depth-first search.  Evaluating patterns like `a?a?a?a` on subject strings like `aaaabaaaa` will be lots of fun, and if you push it too far, may take years to complete.

Your professor chose well the regex operators to give you to make the assignment of meaningful depth, without the tedium of writing a full-on parser and lexer just to make the thing work.

Good luck!